# Query Parent without Childs on the same Object

Tags: soql, query

I am trying to write query to retrieve only Parent records without related Childs on the same object.

The only difference between records is that ParentWorkOrderLineItemId on Parent is empty.

```
SELECT Id, AssetId, WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber, ParentWorkOrderLineItemId
FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE ParentWorkOrderLineItemId != Id
```

Is it possible using SOQL?

Answer (score 3):

The default answer would be to filter based on a subquery, basically identifying all WorkOrderLineItem Id's that do not exist in the ParentWorkOrderLineItemId field.

I.e.

```
SELECT Id, AssetId, WorkOrder.WorkOrderNumber, ParentWorkOrderLineItemId
FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE Id NOT IN (Select ParentWorkOrderLineItemId FROM WorkOrderLineItem)
```

Unfortunately, Salesforce doesn't allow this. You will get the error: `The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type`

You will need to either:

- perform two queries to get the required data. You could feed the resulting ParentWorkOrderLineItemIds of the first query into the second query as a where NOT IN clause filter.
- retrieve all WorkOrderLineItemIds with ParentWorkOrderLineItemIds in one SOQL query and then build up the required sets with code.

Comment: Hi :) I tried this solution previously, but there is an error: ERROR at Row:2:Column:79
The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type

Comment: Darn, you're right. And the bad news is that there is no good solution for this, except handling it in APEX. I will update my answer..